# Special case of radical axis

Tags: geometry, circles

We know that if two chords of two circles intersect at the radical axis, then the four end points of those chords are concyclic. But I do not understand how the case when the two chords are collinear is handled:[image: What is the circle defined by A,B,C and D?]

What is the circle defined by A,B,C and D?

Comment: In that case, the "circle" defined by $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ is the *line* defined defined by $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. When you play with this particular type of geometry, it helps to think of a "line" as a "circle of zero curvature" (or "of infinite radius"). See, for instance, [Descartes' "Kissing Circles" theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem), which relates the curvatures of four mutually-tangent circles; the key formula holds when one or two of the circles are *lines* (circles of zero curvature).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem states that if two ***non-collinear*** chords of two circles intersect at the radical axis, then the four end points of those chords are concyclic. *Collinear* chords will have **inifinite** points of intersection, so it does not make any sense to define this theorem for them.